# How to get Prefix, PageToken, items, bucket and name from FirebaseStorage in flutter?

Tags: flutter

See the code:

```
 final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Posts');

 ref.listAll().then((result) {
      print("Hello: ${result}");
```

So, In my FirebaseStorage, I created one folder called 'Posts' and inside there I manually uploaded some images. Now I somehow found that how to print all of data which is inside Posts folder.

See the output:

```
{prefixes: {}, pageToken: null, items: {header_of_grace_and_beauty_in_summer.jpg: {bucket: hello-465d1.appspot.com, path: /Posts/header_of_grace_and_beauty_in_summer.jpg, name: header_of_grace_and_beauty_in_summer.jpg}, header_of_style_statement_with_valvet.jpg: {bucket: hello-465d1.appspot.com, path: /Posts/header_of_style_statement_with_valvet.jpg, name: header_of_style_statement_with_valvet.jpg}, header_of_dazzling_monsoon.jpeg: {bucket: hello-465d1.appspot.com, path: /Posts/header_of_dazzling_monsoon.jpeg, name: header_of_dazzling_monsoon.jpeg},
```

So, as you can see that there are Prefix, PageToken, items, bucket and name n all. I want name and getDownloadUrl from this list.

How can I do that?

At least someone can just give answer and print that things? I tried but it's just not happening.

EDIT:

```
 //Get 'Posts' stream
  Stream<List<PostData>> get posts {
    ref.listAll().then((value) {
      print('VAL: $value');
      return value;
    });
  }
```

So that I can access like this:

```
final posts = Provider.of<List<PostData>>(context) ?? [];
    pri("VALUE:-> $posts");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
initializing storage bucket
final FirebaseStorage storage =
      FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'Bucket Name');


List<String> image=new List();
var images= ref['items'].keys.toList();
for (var i in images){
   String filePath = 'post/i';
   StorageReference imgref = storage.ref().child(filePath);
   image.add(imgref.getDownloadURL());
}
```

Comment: I already know this. I want to do for all Images. Not manually I want to do write name is a child. And if you'll print result, there are so many things coming. How will I get items and name from that? That is the actual question

Comment: @ShefaliSingh there is a map so you can access items using ref['items'] and you can iterate it to get the URL of all images

Comment: Can you please please please post an answer. If it works I'll surely accepted answer

Comment: @ShefaliSingh please let me know this is working or not

Comment: No, because I want to store this in stream which is typed to model type

Comment: so you need to sink in the stream may be solved your problem

Comment: I'm really new to this. I don't understand what you're saying. Previously I created one demo for listview by watching youtube.Now I'm improving that demo by myself. So my task is to get some images which I uploaded from firebase storage and show in to list view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212552/discussion-between-abhishek-ghaskata-and-shefali-singh).

Comment: Edit my answer just check it @ShefaliSingh

Comment: checked. Tell me how can I store this (List<PostData> list = List<PostData>();) list to this  Stream<List<PostData>> streamList;  ??

Comment: StreamList.sink.add(list); @ShefaliSingh

Comment: there is no sink option